# Used move command in command prompt to rename a file to ~file. Where did the file go?

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

To clarify, this was in a windows system running wsl. The commands were run in windows cmd.exe.

So I was working in command prompt, doing some actions with git and switching between cmd.exe and wsl bash. Afterwards, I wanted to move a script file named "sh" to the home directory of my wsl2 ubuntu distribution.

So without thinking (In command prompt, not bash), I ran this exact command

```
mv sh ~sh
```

I realize now that I made two errors.

1. Since I was not in bash, ~/ is not a valid path
2. Even if I was in bash, I forgot the / in between ~ and sh

**Essentially, my question is where did my file go?**

But also **Why didn't the command just rename the file sh to ~sh?**

I already ran ls -a and dir in the directory in both command prompt and wsl bash. The file wasn't just named to ~sh and left in the directory as far as I can tell. Also for good measure, I searched my ubuntu home folder, but the file is nowhere to be found.

The script wasn't really important, but more I'm curious where it could have gone.

Doing some further digging,
Running: `where mv`

Returns: `C:\Program Files (x86)\WinAVR-20100110\utils\bin\mv.exe`
This leads me to believe that I didn't run the classic linux mv command but `mv --help` just describes essentially the bash mv command "Rename SOURCE to Dest...".

The only section that might be relevant is:

> The backup suffix is `~', unless set with --suffix or SIMPLE_BACKUP_SUFFIX.
> The version control method may be selected via the --backup option or through
> the VERSION_CONTROL environment variable.  Here are the values:

But that doesn't really seem to apply to this usage.

I have looked for if the file is simply hidden and also turned off "hide system protected files" for the folder.

Edit (Copied from comment):

Running:

`mv -i -v example.txt ~sh/example.txt`

Returns:

```
mv: cannot move `example.txt' to `~sh/example.txt'
```

Running:

```
mv -i -v example.txt ~sh
```

Returns:

```
example.txt' -> `/example.txt'
```

Comment: For Linux `/example.txt` implies a move to the root of the filesystem, I'd check if the files are in `C:\`

Comment: That's what I thought of too. But, there it is not there (I checked for hidden/system protected files there also).

Comment: Hmm... wsl; at the bash prompt do `cd / && ls -l` and press enter.

Comment: Yeah, that just lists the C or wsl root depending on whether I run it in wsl or windows. I have already checked those places.

Comment: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install mlocate` - please use your own judgment whether you need the mlocate package. Then do `sudo updatedb && locate -i example.txt`

Comment: cmd.exe?  `cd \ & dir /s /b | find /i "example.txt" `

Comment: All that returns is:
find: /i: No such file or directory
find: example.txt: No such file or directory

Comment: Then you're NOT using cmd.exe; there is a `find` in Linux/bash too - and that `find` has no `/i`type options, it will see `/i` as a reference to an item named `i` in the root of the filesystem, and "example.txt" will be an additonal file to look for (hence the "no such ...")

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `~` meaning your own home directory, bash and other Linux shells also support `~someuser` to refer to *that user's* home directory.

And although you didn't run mv within bash, most such "Linux-utils-on-Windows" ports automatically invoke a compatibility layer which handles shell-like command line processing for them. (They already need it for wildcards/globs.)

So whatever version of mv you invoked thinks that there is a system user named "sh" (according to its /etc/passwd file), and has moved the file into that user's homedir.

Try `mv -v -i someotherfile ~sh/test` to hopefully convince it to reveal the full path that it uses.

Comment: So, I ran mv -v -i example.txt ~sh/example.txt in an administrator mode cmd.exe. The return was:

`example.txt' -> `~sh/example.txt'.
mv: cannot move `example.txt' to `~sh/example.txt'

So I then ran mv -v -i example.txt ~sh and the return was
`example.txt' -> `/example.txt'.


Based on that, I double checked the root directory of my ubuntu wsl distro, but there was nothing there. I also checked C: .

Currently I am running a search of my C drive for example.txt, but as you might imagine that'll take a while.